# $.getJSON works locally but not when uploaded to web server

Tags: jquery, json, apache, getjson

I'm working on a script that is working fine on my local machine but when i upload it to my web server, my $.getJSON request isn't working.

```
function loadData(fileName) {
    return $.getJSON(fileName + ".json");
}

var data;

var myFile = "Data";

loadData(myFile).done(function (data1) {
    if (data1 && data1.info) {
        data = data1;
        $.each(data1.info[0], function (key, value) {
            alert(value);
        });
    }
});
```

I've chopped out a lot of my internal code, which basically just takes the results and puts them into html elements. the url i'm requesting is on a remote server, but it works when i run this html page from my hard drive. when i upload it to my web server its not getting pop, it's like $.getJSON's not even running.

I uploaded it to apache as a folder

```
Folder
|
|-->Index.html
|
|-->Data.json
```

Comment: check your console to see whether there was any errors

Comment: Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: info is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: info
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js
Line 56

Comment: This is the error I get. But if I run it from hard-disk. Its working fine

Comment: Check that you use upper and lower case correctly, on the webserver file names case sensitive.

Comment: I checked it and its fine.

Comment: The whole code is here: http://jsbin.com/ipeseq/12/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't rely on the `$.getJSON()` method, use `$.ajax()` instead: you will have more control on the request headers.

Try it with the following options, and integrate the function call with the parameters peculiar to your application:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some-url.json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

The full documentation of the `$.ajax()` method can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue but it works on remote server and not on local development device (after I imported project from remote server to my new development device).

I finally found that my PHP script throws a notice depending on a $_Session key that wasn't set. The remote *dedicated* server was set to throw no notices wheter my local server was.
The result was that -on my local device- the response couldn't have been parsed as JSON. After I put in an `isset()` command on `$_SESSION` the JSON request was *really* JSON and jQuery parsed it correctly.

Just prove what's your servers response. You can do it with Web Developer -> Web console on Firefox. Just right click on the URL that appears after you send your AJAX request and mark the field to record your request and it's response. You can than inspect the URL after you invoke your AJAX call again and at the bottom of the inspector window you will find it. You directly can see what the response is and if its in correct format.